# Homepage not loading correctly, only after refreshing

Tags: themes, templates, uploads, cache

I'm working on - https://nhukr.org/

When I open the site first I don't see my last changes, sometimes, the site looks like it without CSS.

I cleaned the cache with different plugins. I disable caching on the server, and my hoster said to me that they don't use CDN for my webpage, I changed the theme from Astra to Twenty Twenty-One it also doesn't help.

The problem you can see if you open the webpage on your phone and refresh

Plugins I have:

Elementor

Elementor Pro

Bluehost

Starter Templates

Comment: you definitely have some form of caching plugin running locally, a lot of your CSS files have `wpo-minify` in them, there is definitely more options you can turn off to help with this. What they are though I can't say as I'm not familiar with your sites setup, but this isn't something a random person online can give you an answer to

Answer (score -1):

You can change your current theme to storefront and check whether the scripts and styles are properly enquequed.
use this format to enqueque style and scripts and inspect the code for debugging

```
class yourPluginName {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue'));
    }
    public function enqueue() {
        wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
        wp_enqueue_script('my-js', plugins_url('/script.js', __File__));
        wp_enqueue_style('my-theme', plugins_url('/style.css', __File__));
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the question